# Occurrences in finite alphabet

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Isn't this not true because for the word {aaa}, there is 3 occurrences of a but 0 occurrences of b so #a(y) =/= #b(z)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If we denote $\Lambda$ to be the empty word, then $\{aaa\}=\Lambda+\{aaa\}$. Here, $+$ means concatenation.

---

Here is an example to help you prove the statement.
Let $x=\{abaabba\}$. Try to cut it into two part:
0) $y=\Lambda,z=\{abaabba\}, \#_a(y)=0,\#_b(z)=3$. Invalid.
1) $y=\{a\},z=\{baabba\}, \#_a(y)=1,\#_b(z)=3$. Invalid.
2) $y=\{ab\},z=\{aabba\}, \#_a(y)=1,\#_b(z)=2$. Invalid.
3) $y=\{aba\},z=\{abba\}, \#_a(y)=2,\#_b(z)=2$. Valid.

---

Now consider $x=\{aaaabbb\}$. Is there anything different?
0)...Invalid. 1)...Invalid. 2)...Invalid.
3) $y=\{aaa\},z=\{abbb\}, \#_a(y)=3,\#_b(z)=3$. Valid.

---

A proof is given below:

> Suppose there are $t$ b's in $x$. Then choose $y$ so that the length of it is $t$. Write $x=yz$. If there are $s$ a's in $y$, then $t-a$ b's in $y$, and then $a$ b's in $z$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29482/discussion-on-answer-by-eclipse-sun-occurrences-in-finite-alphabet).